# Limit function to 1 execution youtube player api

Tags: javascript, function, youtube-api, limit, mute

So basically I have embedded a video which should not autoplay and when played be muted, the code works fine but I only want it to run the onStateChange function once otherwise whenever you play/pause the video it mutes the video. Does anyone know how to limit that function to a single execution? Help is much appreciated :)

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
        videoId: 'sAhYEfQ1168',
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 0,
            'controls': 0,
            'autohide': 1,
            'wmode': 'opaque',
            'showinfo': 0,
            'loop': 1,
            'fs':0,
            'rel':0
        },
        events: {
           'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });

}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.mute();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the `onReady` property of `player.events` object to `null` within and at last line of `onPlayerReady` function

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.mute();
    player.events.onReady = null;
}
```

Comment: Actually managed to use your answer but using the event "onReady". Thanks man!

Comment: @IndianaPorter Suggested edit contains different references than original Question; original Question still references `onStateChange`, `onPlayerStateChange`. Perhaps update original Question? The pattern is the same.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that "onStateChange" uses the following states:

```
-1 (unstarted)
0 (ended)
1 (playing)
2 (paused)
3 (buffering)
5 (video cued)
```

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=de

The event with the a data of "-1" seems to be executed only once on the first run.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/w4d6t32m/

If you only want to mute the video you might also look into the "onReady" event.

Comment: Thanks mate! came to the same conclusion just as you posted this :) Thanks for the help!